# Retrieving DB Schema Visualization of Neo4j DB using Springboot/Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to retrieve "call db.schema.visualization()" query using Springboot and Kotlin.

With the code I have written, I am able to fetch all data of schema but only able to write the keys from the response after calling the query method. Please have a look at the code and help me with it.

Repository:

```
@Repository
interface CustomMovieRepository {
    fun schemaVisualization(): Optional<MutableMap<String, Any>>
}
```

RepositoryImpl:

```
class CustomMovieRepositoryImpl(@Autowired val client: Neo4jClient) : CustomMovieRepository {

    override fun schemaVisualization(): Optional<MutableMap<String, Any>> {
        val all = client.query("call db.schema.visualization()").fetch().one()
        return all

    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
 @GetMapping("/schema-visualization", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun SchemaVisualization(): Optional<MutableMap<String, Any>> {
        return movieRepository.schemaVisualization()
    }
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]]

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct. But you are just not seeing what's inside because there is no accessor for the properties.
If you want to have more details, you have to map this manually. Here is a small example to get you started.

```
record Visualization(Collection<VisualizationNode> nodes, Collection<VisualizationRelationship> relationships) {}
record VisualizationNode(Iterable<String> labels, Map<String, Object> properties) {}
record VisualizationRelationship(String type, Map<String, Object> properties) {}

@Test
void testing(@Autowired Neo4jClient client, @Autowired Driver driver) {
    try (var session = driver.session()) {
        session.run("CREATE (u:User)-[:KNOWS]->(:Language)").consume();
    }
    var one = client.query("CALL db.schema.visualization()")
            .fetchAs(Visualization.class)
            .mappedBy((typeSystem, record) -> {
                var nodes = record.get("nodes").asList(Value::asNode)
                        .stream().map(node -> new VisualizationNode(node.labels(), node.asMap())).toList();
                var relationships = record.get("relationships").asList(Value::asRelationship)
                        .stream().map(relationship -> new VisualizationRelationship(relationship.type(), relationship.asMap())).toList();
                return new Visualization(nodes, relationships);
            })
            .one();
    System.out.println(one.get());
}
```

Will output

```
Visualization[
nodes=[VisualizationNode[labels=[User], properties={name=User, indexes=[], constraints=[]}], VisualizationNode[labels=[Language], properties={name=Language, indexes=[], constraints=[]}],...]],
relationships=[VisualizationRelationship[type=KNOWS, properties={}]]
]
```

Edit: There is also an unofficial, experimental plugin that you might want to check: https://github.com/neo4j/graph-schema-introspector
Some background on this: https://medium.com/neo4j/describing-a-property-graph-data-model-d203c389546e